# RAID Lag-Behind Burst Write

Tags: linux, raid, cache, software-raid, raid1

I would like to setup RAID1 so that a ramdisk in the RAID configuration has occasional synchronisation with a physical disk (that is very battery intensive to run, so I hope to let it spinout).

Is there a way I can set the commission frequency on the RAID config such that it will only burst-write to the HDD every, let's say, 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `mdadm` for your software-raid-1 and set it up with a dirty-map, you could connect/disconnect that disk every N seconds to the md-device.

In md-terms that is

- set faulty
- remove
- re-add

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some FSes you can have such tweaks, say for EXT3, EXT4 `man mount` mentions «…

> commit=nrsec Sync all data and metadata every nrsec seconds. The default value is 5 seconds. Zero means default.

…» — That might suffice for your needs.

Also, there's `vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs` sysctl which is described as: «…

> The pdflush writeback daemons will periodically wake up and write `old' data
>   out to disk.  This tunable expresses the interval between those wakeups, in
>   100'ths of a second.
>
> Setting this to zero disables periodic writeback altogether.

…»

So, actually probably you don't have to mess with RAM-disk/HDD RAID1 at all.

Comment: Thanks, but those options allocate more RAM so I'll end up storing stuff twice. I probably could end up not using a ramdisk, but I really like the performance that I can get out of it; and in any case, it's a learning experience.

Comment: @kvanberendonck, «storing stuff twice» — why is that? )